# How to fix this likelihood in python and plot it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, statistics

For a linear logistic regression model formulated as follows:
[image: picture]

I was trying to code the likelihood and plot it to see what it looks like. This is how I've implemented it:

```
# Define likelihood function
def likelihood(beta):
    # reshape correctly
    beta = np.array(beta).reshape(-1, 1)
    # X beta has x_i^T * \beta in every entry
    Xbeta = np.matmul(X, beta).flatten()
    exp_argument = np.multiply(newrows.y.values, Xbeta)
    numerator = np.exp(exp_argument.sum())
    denominator = np.prod((1 + np.exp(Xbeta)))
    return numerator / denominator
# Prepare a grid
b1 = np.linspace(-10, -8.5, 100)   # these values chosen by trial and error
b2 = np.linspace(4.5, 6.2, 100)    # these values chosen by trial and error
B1, B2 = np.meshgrid(b1, b2)
# Evaluate function at the gridpoints
Zbeta = np.array([likelihood(thing) for thing in zip(B1.ravel(), B2.ravel())])
Zbeta = Zbeta.reshape(B1.shape)
# Surface plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(B1, B2, Zbeta)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.contour(B1, B2, Zbeta)
plt.show()
```

Here the matrix `X` is a matrix containing "fake" Bernoulli observations. It is a well known dataset called BeetleMortality, which looks like this and I've stored it in a Pandas Dataframe called `data`.

[image: figure2]

which are basically Binomial observations. I've created Bernoulli observations as follows:

```
newrows = np.zeros((data.NumberExposed.sum(), 2))
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    obs = np.zeros(int(row.NumberExposed), dtype=int)
    obs[:int(row.NumberKilled)] = 1
    np.random.shuffle(obs)
    obs = obs.reshape(-1, 1)
    doses = np.repeat(row.Dose, len(obs)).reshape(-1, 1)
    obs = np.hstack((doses, obs))
    from_index = int(row.CumulativeN - row.NumberExposed)
    to_index = int(row.CumulativeN)
    newrows[from_index:to_index] = obs 
# Save it as a dataframe
newrows = pd.DataFrame(newrows, columns=['x', 'y'])
# Notice that if you wanted to check that these calculations are correct use: newrows.groupby('x').sum()
newrows.head()
```

Everything seems to work fine, except that when I try to plot this I obtain the following plot:

[image: figure3]

Which makes absolutely no sense.. Any help? Maybe I'm implementing the likelihood function in the wrong way?

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but on the face of it, the plot you showed seems plausible. It's typical that the likelihood function is very strongly peaked -- that just means almost all parameters are not very good, and you only get a reasonable fit in a very narrow neighborhood. That's quite typical of parameter-fitting problems. By the way, try plotting the logarithm of the likelihood in order to make the range more tractable.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem, it looks like the limits and the plots are similar enough that it isn't surprising. Are you having problems with the results or how the 2D plot relates to the 3D plot? If so, I'd suggest looking at your number of levels and/or your cmap. Maybe even use a filled contour too.

Comment: I am not sure the product operator is correctly implemented. I would double check the numerator and denominator variables.

Comment: What are you expecting the plot to look like?